# CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. Unity

Tags: unity3d, android-sdk, unity3d-android

После добавления *Vungle* в *Unity* при билде проекта появились ошибки (до этого проект билдился без ошибок).

На момент добавления *Vungle* уже были доданы *Unity Ads/Analytics*, *AdMob*, *Firebase (Messagess, Analytics)*.

Использую : *Unity version - 2017.3.0f3; jdk - 1.8.0_152, Android ADK - 25.2.5*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Текст ошибки*:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
E:\ProgramFiles\_toolchains\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "E:/ProgramFiles/_toolchains/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.admob.impl.license:com.google.android.gms.admob:com.google.android.gms.admob.license:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.base.license:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.common.license:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.gass.license:com.google.android.gms.tasks:com.google.android.gms.tasks.license:com.google.firebase.measurement:com.google.firebase.measurement_impl:com.google.firebase.measurement.impl.license:com.google.firebase.measurement.license:com.google.firebase.unity.analytics:com.google.firebase.unity.app:com.google.firebase.firebase_common:com.google.firebase.firebase.common.license:com.google.firebase.firebase_core:com.google.firebase.iid:com.google.firebase.firebase.iid.license:com.google.firebase.messaging:com.google.firebase.firebase.messaging.license:com.google.firebase.unity.messaging:com.google.firebase.unity:com.google.android.gms:com.google.unity.ads:com.unity3d.ads:com.vungle.vungle_lib -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-core-ui-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-core-utils-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-fragment-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-media-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-v4-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-gass-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-common-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-messaging-11.8.0\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Firebase\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res" -S "E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-ads\res"

stderr[
E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\values\values.xml:34: error: Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with incompatible format.
E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_attrs.xml:13: Original attribute defined here.
]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
Including resources from package: E:\ProgramFiles\_toolchains\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_ic_googleplayservices.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_normal_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_normal_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_pressed_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=powered_by_google_dark.png
trying overlaySet Key=powered_by_google_light.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
baseFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
baseFile 1 has flavor tvdpi-v4
baseFile 2 has flavor hdpi-v4
baseFile 3 has flavor xhdpi-v4
baseFile 4 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
overlayFile 0 has flavor hdpi-v4
overlayFile 1 has flavor xhdpi-v4
found a match (2) for overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor hdpi-v4
found a match (3) for overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_disabled.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=googleg_disabled_color_18.png
trying overlaySet Key=googleg_standard_color_18.png
trying overlaySet Key=app_banner.png
trying overlaySet Key=app_icon.png
applyFileOverlay for layout
applyFileOverlay for anim
applyFileOverlay for animator
applyFileOverlay for interpolator
applyFileOverlay for transition
applyFileOverlay for xml
applyFileOverlay for raw
trying overlaySet Key=gtm_analytics
applyFileOverlay for color
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=wallet_primary_text_holo_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=wallet_secondary_text_holo_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_tint.xml
applyFileOverlay for menu
applyFileOverlay for mipmap
Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
Processing image: res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-mdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png: 56% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-tvdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png: 45% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png: 120% size of source)
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png: 105% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_full_open_on_phone.png: 45% size of source)
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png: 164% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png: 151% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png: 138% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png: 169% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png: 90% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png: 146% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png: 136% size of source)
    (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png: 93% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png: 135% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png: 152% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png: 134% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png: 129% size of source)
    (processed image E:\Unity\_Projects\TapBall\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png: 130% size of source)
Processing image: E:\Unity\_<message truncated>
```

! Пробывал разные Android SDK, изменял манифест, удалял все либы, пересавлял Vungle - не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня была такая же проблема. Оказалось что с *Vungle* додалась папка **Assets/Plugins/Android/google-play-services_lib/**, удалив её проблемы не стало!

Comment: Огромное спаисбо, помогло))